# Nowcasting Y with known X, using VECM in R

Tags: r, modeling, forecasting

I am trying to nowcast a time series data (Y) using another time series (X) as a predictor. X and Y are cointegrated. Y is a monthly data from Jan 2012 to Oct 2016 and X runs from Jan 2012 to Feb 2017.

So, I ran VECM as it shown in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x9DcUA9puY0

Than, to obtain a predicted values, I transformed it in VAR by `vec2var` command, following information from this topic: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/223888/how-to-forecast-from-vecm-in-r

But I can not forecast Y with known X, how it can be made using `predict` function with a linear regression model. Also, I can not obtain modelled Y (Y hat) values.

This is my code:

```
# Cointegrated_series is a ZOO object, which contains two time series X and Y

library("zoo") 
library("xts") 
library("urca")
library("vars")

# Obtain lag length
Lagl <- VARselect(Cointegrated_series)$selection[[1]]

#Conduct Eigen test
cointest <- ca.jo(Cointegrated_series,K=Lagl,type = "eigen", ecdet = "const", 
                    spec = "transitory")
#Fit VECM
vecm <- cajorls(cointest)

#Transform VECM to VAR
var <- vec2var(cointest)
```

Than I'm trying to use `predict` function in different ways: `predict(var)`, `predict(var, newdata = 50)`, `predict(var, newdata = 1000)` - result is the same.

Tried to use `tsDyn` package and `newdata` argument in `predict` method, as it mentioned here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/261849/prediction-from-vecm-in-r-using-external-forecasts-of-regressors?rq=1

Not working. My newdata is a ZOO object, where X series has values from Nov 2016 to Feb 2017, and Y series are NAs. So, the method returns NAs in forecast:

```
    # Cointegrated_series is a ZOO object, which contains 
#two time series X and Y from Jan 2012 to Oct 2016. Both X and Y are values.
    # newDat is a ZOO object, which contains two time series 
#X and Y from Nov 2016 to Feb 2017. X are values, Y are NAs.

    library(tsDyn)

    vecm <-VECM(Cointegrated_series, lag=2)

    predict(vecm,newdata = newDat, n.ahead=5)
```

This is a result:

```
                                                    Y             X
59                                                  NA            NA
60                                                  NA            NA
61                                                  NA            NA
62                                                  NA            NA
63                                                  NA            NA
```

For example, this is what I get after calling `predict` whithout `newdata` argument:

```
predict(vecm, n.ahead=5)

                                              Y             X
59                                            65.05233      64.78006
60                                            70.54545      73.87368
61                                            75.65266      72.06513
62                                            74.76065      62.97242
63                                            70.03992      55.81045
```

So, my main questions are:

1. How to nowcast Y with known X, using VEC model in R?
2. How to obtain modelled Y (Y hat) values?

Besides that, I also couldn't find an answer on these questions:

3. How to call Akaike criteria (AIC) for VECM in R?
4. Does vars and urca packages provide F and t statistics for VECM?

**UPD 10.04.2017**
I slightly edited the question. Noticed, that my problem applies to a "ragged edge" problem, and it's incorrect to call it "forecasting" - it is "nowcasting".

**UPD 11.04.2017**

Thank you for answering!

Here is the full code:

```
library("lubridate")
library("zoo")
library("xts") 
library("urca")
library("vars")
library("forecast") 



Dat <- dget(file = "https://getfile.dokpub.com/yandex/get/https://yadi.sk/d/VJpQ75Rz3GsDKN")
NewDat <- dget(file = "https://getfile.dokpub.com/yandex/get/https://yadi.sk/d/T7qxxPUq3GsDLc")



Lagl <- VARselect(Dat)$selection[[1]]

#vars package

cointest_e <- ca.jo(Dat,K=Lagl,type = "eigen", ecdet = "const", 
                    spec = "transitory")


vecm <- cajorls(cointest_e)

var <- vec2var(cointest_e)

Predict1 <- predict(var)

Predict2 <- predict(var, newdata = NewDat)

Predict1$fcst$Y
Predict2$fcst$Y

Predict1$fcst$Y == Predict2$fcst$Y
Predict1$fcst$X == Predict2$fcst$X

#As we see, Predict1 and Predict2 are similar, so the information in NewDat
#didn't came into account.

library("tsDyn")

vecm2 <-VECM(Dat, lag=3)

predict(vecm2)
predict(vecm2, newdata=NewDat)
```

If `dget` will return an error, please, download my data here:

https://yadi.sk/d/VJpQ75Rz3GsDKN - for Dat

https://yadi.sk/d/T7qxxPUq3GsDLc - for NewDat

**About nowcasting**

Saying *Nowcasting* I mean current-month or previous-month forecasts of unavailible data with currently availible data. Here are some referenses:

Gianonne, Reichlin, Small: Nowcasting: The real-time informational content of macroeconomic data (2008)

Now-Casting and the Real-time Data Flow (2013)

Marcellino, Schumacher: Factor MIDAS for Nowcasting and Forecasting with Ragged-Edge Data: A Model Comparison for German GDP (2010)

Comment: Can you be more precise as what you mean by nowcasting? Why would go take n.ahead=5? And how does your newdata argument look like?

Comment: Could you provide a minimal subset of your data?

Comment: I updated the post, added reproducible code with my data. Hope, that it's all clear now. n.ahead=5 wasn't nessesary now, indeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I feel your question is more about how to do nowcasting for cointegrated variables, then let's see later how to implement it in R.

In general, according to Granger's representation theorem, cointegrated variables can be represented in multiple forms:

- Long term relationship: contemporaneous values of y and x
- VECM representation: (diff of) y and x explained by (diff of) lags, and error-correction term at previous period.

So I am not sure how you would do nowcasting in the VECM representation, since it includes only past values? I can see two possibilities:

1. Do nowcasting based on the long-term relationship. So you just run standard OLS, and predict from there.
2. Do nowcasting based on a structural VECM, where you add contemporaneous values of the variables you know (X). In R, you would do this package `urca`, you need though to check whether the `predict` function will allow you to add know X values.

Regarding the long-term relationship approach, what is interesting is that you can obtain forecasts for X and Y based on the VECM (without known X) and from the LT with known X. This gives you a way to have an idea of the accuracy of your model (comparing known and predicted X), which you could use to create a forecast averaging scheme for your Y?

Comment: Wel, it seems like the problem is rooted in my understanding of VECM and cointegration, not R functions. The fact that VECM includes only past values clarifies a lot.

As I know, `predict` function doesn't allow to add known X values when running with VECM.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, thank you so much @Matifou for your awesome package.
I am late in responding, but I was also struggling to figure out the same question and I did not find a solution. That is why I implemented the following function, I hope it will be useful for some people:

```
#' @title Special predict method for VECM models
#' @description Predict method for VECM models given some known endogenus
#'  variables are known but one. It is just valid for one cointegration equation by the moment
#' @param object, an object of class ‘VECM’
#' @param new_data, a dataframe containing the forecast of all the endogenus variables
#'  but one, if there are exogenus variables, its forecast must be provided.
#' @param predicted_var, a string with the desired endogenus variable to be predicted.
#' @return A list with the predicted variable, predicted values and a dataframe with the
#' detailed values used for the construction of the forecast.
#' @examples
#' data(zeroyld)
#' # Fit a VECM with Johansen MLE estimator:
#' vecm.jo<-VECM(zeroyld, lag=2, estim="ML")
#' predict.vecm(vecm.jo, new_data = data.frame("long.run" = c(7:10)), predicted_var = "short.run")

predict.vecm <- function(object, new_data, predicted_var){
  if (inherits(object, "VECM")) {
    # Just valid for VECM models
    # Get endogenus and exogenus variables
    summary_vecm <- summary(object)
    model_vars <- colnames(object$model)
    endovars <- sub("Equation ", "", rownames(summary_vecm$bigcoefficients))
    if (!(predicted_var %in% endovars)) {
      stop("You must provide a valid endogenus variable.")
    }
    exovars <- NULL
    if (object$exogen) {
      ind_endovars <-
        unlist(sapply(endovars, function(x) grep(x, model_vars), simplify = FALSE))
      exovars <- model_vars[-ind_endovars]
      exovars <- exovars[exovars != "ECT"]
    }

    # First step: join new_data and (lags + 1) last values from the calibration data
    new_data <- data.frame(new_data)
    if (!all(colnames(new_data) %in% c(endovars, exovars))) {
      stop("new_data must have valid endogenus or exogenus column names.")
    }
    # Endovars but the one desired to be predicted
    endovars2 <- endovars[endovars != predicted_var]
    # if (!all(colnames(new_data) %in% c(endovars2, exovars))) {
    #   stop("new_data must have valid endogenus (all but the one desired to predict) or exogenus column names.")
    # }
    new_data <- new_data[, c(endovars2, exovars), drop = FALSE]
    new_data <- cbind(NA, new_data)
    colnames(new_data) <- c(predicted_var, endovars2, exovars)
    # Previous values to obtain lag values and first differences (lags + 1)
    dt_tail <- data.frame(tail(object$model[, c(endovars, exovars), drop = FALSE], object$lag + 1))
    new_data <- rbind(dt_tail, new_data)

    # Second step: get long rung relationship forecast (ECT term)
    ect_vars <- rownames(object$model.specific$beta)
    if ("const" %in% ect_vars) {
      new_data$const <- 1
    }
    ect_coeff <- object$model.specific$beta[, 1]
    new_data$ECT_0 <-
      apply(sweep(new_data[, ect_vars], MARGIN = 2, ect_coeff, `*`), MARGIN = 1, sum)
    # Get ECT-1 (Lag 1)
    new_data$ECT <- as.numeric(quantmod::Lag(new_data$ECT_0, 1))

    # Third step: get differences of the endogenus and exogenus variables provided in new_data
    diff_data <- apply(new_data[, c(endovars, exovars)], MARGIN = 2, diff)
    colnames(diff_data) <- paste0("DIFF_", c(endovars, exovars))
    diff_data <- rbind(NA, diff_data)
    new_data <- cbind(new_data, diff_data)

    # Fourth step: get x lags of the endogenus and exogenus variables
    for (k in 1:object$lag) {
      iter <- myLag(new_data[, paste0("DIFF_", endovars)], k)
      colnames(iter) <- paste0("DIFF_", endovars, " -", k)
      new_data <- cbind(new_data, iter)
    }

    # Fifth step: recursive calculatioon
    vecm_vars <- colnames(summary_vecm$bigcoefficients)
    if ("Intercept" %in% vecm_vars) {
      new_data$Intercept <- 1
    }
    vecm_vars[!(vecm_vars %in% c("ECT", "Intercept"))] <-
      paste0("DIFF_", vecm_vars[!(vecm_vars %in% c("ECT", "Intercept"))])
    equation <- paste("Equation", predicted_var)
    equation_coeff <- summary_vecm$coefficients[equation, ]
    predicted_var2 <- paste0("DIFF_", predicted_var)
    for (k in (object$lag + 2):nrow(new_data)) {
      # Estimate y_diff
      new_data[k, predicted_var2] <-
        sum(sweep(new_data[k, vecm_vars], MARGIN = 2, equation_coeff, `*`))
      # Estimate y_diff lags
      for (j in 1:object$lag) {
        new_data[, paste0(predicted_var2, " -", j)] <-
          as.numeric(quantmod::Lag(new_data[, predicted_var2], j))
      }
      # Estimate y
      new_data[k, predicted_var] <-
        new_data[(k - 1), predicted_var] + new_data[k, predicted_var2]
      # Estimate ECT
      new_data[k, "ECT_0"] <- sum(sweep(new_data[k, ect_vars], MARGIN = 2, ect_coeff, `*`))
      if (k < nrow(new_data)) {
        new_data[k + 1, "ECT"] <- new_data[k, "ECT_0"]
      }
    }
    predicted_values <- new_data[(object$lag + 2):nrow(new_data), predicted_var]
  } else {
    stop("You must provide a valid VECM model.")
  }

  return(
    list(
      predicted_variable = predicted_var,
      predicted_values = predicted_values,
      data = new_data
    )
  )
}


# Lag function applied to dataframes
myLag <- function(data, lag) data.frame(unclass(data[c(rep(NA, lag), 1:(nrow(data)-`lag)),]))`
```

@Andrey Goloborodko, in your example, you should apply:

```
NewDat <- NewDat[-1,] #Just new data is necessary to be provided
predict.vecm(vecm2, new_data=NewDat, predicted_var = "Y")
# $predicted_variable
# [1] "Y"
# 
# $predicted_values
# [1] 65.05233 61.29563 59.45109
# 
# $data
#                  Y   X       ECT_0         ECT     DIFF_Y DIFF_X  DIFF_Y -1 DIFF_X -1  DIFF_Y -2
# jul. 2016 92.40506 100 -29.0616718          NA         NA     NA         NA        NA         NA
# ago. 2016 94.03255  78  -0.7115037 -29.0616718   1.627486    -22         NA        NA         NA
# sep. 2016 78.84268  53  14.4653067  -0.7115037 -15.189873    -25   1.627486       -22         NA
# oct. 2016 67.99277  52   4.8300645  14.4653067 -10.849910     -1 -15.189873       -25   1.627486
# nov. 2016 65.05233  51   3.1042967   4.8300645  -2.940435     -1 -10.849910        -1 -15.189873
# dic. 2016 61.29563  50   0.5622618   3.1042967  -3.756702     -1  -2.940435        -1 -10.849910
# ene. 2017 59.45109  55  -7.3556104   0.5622618  -1.844535      5  -3.756702        -1  -2.940435
#           DIFF_X -2  DIFF_Y -3 DIFF_X -3 Intercept
# jul. 2016        NA         NA        NA         1
# ago. 2016        NA         NA        NA         1
# sep. 2016        NA         NA        NA         1
# oct. 2016       -22         NA        NA         1
# nov. 2016       -25   1.627486       -22         1
# dic. 2016        -1 -15.189873       -25         1
# ene. 2017        -1 -10.849910        -1         1
```